# LikeButton with graphql_flutter - animation does not working

Tags: flutter, graphql-codegen, graphql-flutter, fbsdklikebutton

I have code with graphql_flutter(graphql_codegen) and like_button.
I should call to Mutation when user click the like_button.
when I do it, and call to RunMutation the animation into like_button stopped work.
how can I fix it?
I added the relevant lines from StatelessWidget:

```
Mutation$updateUserIdsLikes$Widget(
  builder: (runMutation, result) {
    return LikeButton(onTap: (isLiked) async {
      runMutation(Variables$Mutation$updateUserIdsLikes(
              questionId: question.$_id,
              action: Enum$UserAction.ADD))
          .toString();
      return Future(() => !isLiked);
    });
  },
),
```

(when I remove the runMutation from onTap the animation working ok.)

I'll try call to Graphql and see the animation.